# Is it possible to get a nested svg element to not clip its contents?

Tags: svg

I need to set a new coordinate system so I can get some gradient stuff to work. Using a svg element (with x and y attrs) inside another svg element instead of a 'g' (with transform) works but now I can't draw outside. Is there any way to make a nested svg element not clip its contents? Or another way to do this?

My gradient indicates sentiment and I am drawing a number of bars filled with the gradient. I need to use gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" to ensure they are coloured correctly and not according to their own bounds.

Comment: you can use overflow: visible; but you really shouldn't it's not great for performance.

Comment: Ah, you're right @RobertLongson. Learned something new.

Comment: Overflow: visible works! tx. I can't see any noticeable perf impact. If you post an answer I will tick it. @RobertLongson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow: visible works! tx. I can't see any noticeable perf impact.